# Dúvida com comando DROP COLUMN sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tentei excluir uma coluna de um banco de dados, verifiquei que existem restrições.

ALTER TABLE dbo.TB_ESTRACAO DROP COLUMN MULTIPLICADOR

Recebo uma mensagem , como posso resolver isso? Agradeço!

> Mensagem 5074, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
>   The object 'DF_TB_ESTRACAO_MULTIPLICADOR' is dependent on column 'MULTIPLICADOR'.
>   Mensagem 4922, Nível 16, Estado 9, Linha 1
>   ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN MULTIPLICADOR failed because one or more objects access this column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mensagem indica que foi criada uma restrição (constraint) com valor default para a coluna que estamos tentando excluir. Antes de excluir esta coluna, a restrição deve ser excluída.

ALTER TABLE TB_ESTRACAO
DROP CONSTRAINT DF_TB_ESTRACAO_MULTIPLICADOR

Em seguida poderemos excluir a coluna:

ALTER TABLE TB_ESTRACAO 
DROP COLUMN MULTIPLICADOR

Answer (score 1):

A mensagem de erro diz que o objeto `DF_TB_ESTRACAO_MULTIPLICADOR` faz referência a coluna `dbo.TB_ESTRACAO.MULTIPLICADOR` e por isso você não pode excluí-la.

As seguintes queries podem ajudar a entender quem depende de quem:

Buscando Objetos que dependem da coluna:

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID),definition
FROM
    sys.sql_modules
WHERE
    definition LIKE '%MULTIPLICADOR%'
```

Buscando Stored Procedures que dependem da coluna:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID),
    object_definition(OBJECT_ID)
FROM
    sys.Procedures
WHERE
    object_definition(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%MULTIPLICADOR%'
```

Espero ter ajudado!